# How do I correctly set up Application Request Routing in IIS7 to route SSL requests?

Tags: iis-7, ssl

I have a 3-node web farm being managed by IIS7 and Application Request Routing.  I have a folder hierarchy in my web app that needs to be secured via SSL.  What is the best practice for getting ARR to correctly route these SSL requests?  I have installed the same certificate on all web farm servers and the server running ARR.  I have tried enabling and disabling the SSL Off-loading feature

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot.  I forgot to open SSL through our firewall.